# What's the difference between Google cardboard sdk and google vr for unity sdk?

Tags: google-cardboard, google-vr

I've seen several tutorials for creating a mobile VR app with Unity.

Some of them are using the Cardboard SDK and others are using the Google VR SDK.

What's the main difference and is there a recommendation to use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

Google VR SDK is newer and also supports the Daydream platform: https://vr.google.com/daydream/

The Google VR SDK is the latest SDK and supports new features including low-latency rendering and the new input methods.

-Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

They are basically same but Google VR SDK is the latest SDK and it supports Daydream platform.

Cardboard apps will support both normal phones and daydream supported phones without change anything when updated to the latest Google VR SDK.So, better to use Google VR SDK.